# MySQL how to sort the lowest value/price of a table, and only show the name of the lowest?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want have a database with hotelrooms where guest can make a reservation. I want to show the cheapest hotelroom per city, if prices are the same, I want to show both cities. How do I do this. I am a beginner in Sql, so I have trouble solving this.

What I currently have:

```
| type       | pID        |city           |price    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|----------
| B          |  COD12      |    Canvas    |  240    |
| B          |  COD40      |    Canvas    |  200    |
| B          |  KHOD20     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  KHOD60     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
```

What I want:

```
| type        | pID        |city          |price    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|----------
| B          |  COD40      |    Canvas    |  200    |
| B          |  KHOD20     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
| B          |  KHOD60     |    Kentucky  |  40     |
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, where's the city of Kentucky? Where's Canvas?

Comment: @Strawberry Kentucky is in Michigan (and Australia), and Canvas is in West Virginia.

Comment: @Shawn using the term 'city' a little loosely there - but nice googling. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This SQL gives you want you described

```
select type,pID,city,price
  from your table 
 where (city, price) 
    in (select city, min(price) 
          from your table 
         group by 1)
```

The subquery finds out minimum prices for each city, passes city and price information to main query as a filter. Using this filter main query returns all rows matches with city / price pairs.

Comment: There's no need to compare on city .

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, it would be interesting to compare mdem7's answer to a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.city = t.city);
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(city, price)`.

In MySQL 8+, this is a good place for window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by city order by price) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```